# Codacy feature in github is giving me some errors I can't understand

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, codacy

I have a repository with Codacy incorporated to check the quality of my code. When trying to do a commit I'm getting these two errors that I don't know how to fix... any help?

**Expected property shorthand.**

in this line: `this.state.notifications.push({name: name, url: inboxFolder.files[parseInt(index)].url});`

**Found fs.readFile with non literal argument at index 0**

in this line: `let fol = await this.fc.readFile(url.toString());`

Answer (score 2):

The first error can be solved with the following code lines:

```rb
let url = inboxFolder.files[parseInt(index)].url;
this.state.notifications.push({name, url});
```

Answer (score 1):

Codacy is recommending to use 2 good practices on javascript language

1. Use property shorthand syntax (https://alligator.io/js/object-property-shorthand-es6/)

```
let url = inboxFolder.files[parseInt(index)].url;
this.state.notifications.push({name, url});
```

2. there may be something on the context / surrounding lines, but it seems to recomment not using a variable as file to read. this is probably because it may be user input, and it's not validated, hence it may bring security problems